# MSSQL XML value returns no result

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008-r2, xquery

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 to to parse an XML, but it return no result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ymaps xmlns="http://maps.yandex.ru/ymaps/1.x" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="     http://maps.yandex.ru/business/1.x http://maps.yandex.ru/schemas/business/1.x/business.xsd     http://maps.yandex.ru/geocoder/1.x http://maps.yandex.ru/schemas/geocoder/1.x/geocoder.xsd     http://maps.yandex.ru/psearch/1.x http://maps.yandex.ru/schemas/psearch/1.x/psearch.xsd     http://maps.yandex.ru/search/1.x http://maps.yandex.ru/schemas/search/1.x/search.xsd     http://maps.yandex.ru/web/1.x http://maps.yandex.ru/schemas/web/1.x/web.xsd     http://maps.yandex.ru/search/internal/1.x ../../search/internal/1.x/internal.xsd">
   <Attribution xmlns="http://maps.yandex.ru/attribution/1.x" />
   <GeoObjectCollection>
      <featureMember xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
         <GeoObject xmlns="http://maps.yandex.ru/ymaps/1.x">
            <Point xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
               <pos>47.248887 56.143900</pos>
            </Point>
         </GeoObject>
      </featureMember>
   </GeoObjectCollection>
</ymaps>
```

Code:

```
SELECT @XML.value('(/ymaps/GeoObjectCollection/featureMember/GeoObject/Point/pos) [1]', 'varchar(255)')
```

Is there any other good method to do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two different default namespaces declared in various level of the XML. Note that given a default namespace, the element where the default namespace declared and all of it's descendants without prefix and without different default namespace are considered within the same namespace.

You can use [`;WITH XMLNAMESPACES()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177400.aspx) to register default namespace and namespace prefix :

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://www.opengis.net/gml' as ns,
                     DEFAULT 'http://maps.yandex.ru/ymaps/1.x')
SELECT @XML.value('(/ymaps/GeoObjectCollection/ns:featureMember/GeoObject/ns:Point/ns:pos) [1]', 'varchar(255)')
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/37910)**

Answer (score 0):

You have two likely problems:

1) You are missing the namespaces from your XPath expression and so it will not match.

2) You have a space between the expression and the predicate.

Try instead:

```
SELECT @XML.value('(/*:ymaps/*:GeoObjectCollection/*:featureMember/*:GeoObject/*:Point/*:pos)[1]', 'varchar(255)')
```

I do not know how to easily manage namespaces in MSSQL XML, so I have used `*` which means *any namespace*.